# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'randint' in Hyperopt

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, hyperopt

I'm trying to adjust a random forest as a Hyperopt, but this error is occurring and I can't solve it

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not include code/errors as images. Somewhere you have a variable called hp that shadows the hp package in hyperopt

Answer (score 1):

Here, `rstate` parameter of `fmin()` function needs random number generator which can be provided by `np.random.RandomState(seed)`. However, you have passed an integer value (i.e., `rstate=42`) and that is why it is showing

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'randint'

Therefore, simply replacing that value (i.e., 42) by `np.random.RandomState(42)` will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `rstate=np.random.default_rng(seed=42)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This was due to the method np.random.RandomState was deprecated. Hyperopt now uses np.random.Generator().

You can use the **rstate=np.random.default_rng(42)**

This can fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have resolved this yet but I think you can't set 'rstate' as an integer in this method, I had the same issue and it's resolve since I stopped setting 'rstate'

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)